# ZF2 Call to a member function get() on null using $this->getServiceLocator()->get()

Tags: php, zend-framework2

My first controller is

```
class MatchesController extends AbstractActionController {
    public function checkLogsAction() {
        // $logs=new LogsController();

        $logs=$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Admin\LogsController');
        $logs->writeLogs("log data");
        die();
    }
```

Logs Controller

```
class LogsController extends AbstractActionController {

    public function writeLogs($logData) {
        $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Log\opta')->info($logData);
        return true;
    }
```

global.php

```
'service_manager' => array(
         'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'   => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',

            'Zend\Log\opta' => function ($sm) {
                $fileName=date("Y-m-d");
                $log = new Zend\Log\Logger();
                $writer = new Zend\Log\Writer\Stream("./data/opta/$fileName");
                $log->addWriter($writer);

                return $log;
            }
         ),
     ),
```

module.php

```
public function getServiceConfig() {
        return array(
            "factories"=>array(
                'Admin\LogsController' => function ($sm) {
                    $logsController = new LogsController();
                    return $logsController;
                },
```

I am getting this error: 
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on null

Please help me to solve the solution

Comment: Are you sure you are using zf2 not zf3, because $this->getServiceLocator(), was deprecated in zf3,

Comment: $this->getServiceLocator() was deprecated in zf2.5 and removed in zf3. Try injecting your dependancies into your controller with a factory. If you are looking for a logging system then take a look at https://github.com/krytenuk/logger.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Admin\LogsController` extends AbstractActionController. But you do not use it as `AbstractActionController`!

An AbstractActionController is usuallay invoked by processing the (http) request, whereby the ZF2 application is going to route the request to a controller and executes an action method. During this processing, an instance of ServiceLocator/ServiceManager is passed to the controller. That is what you are missing. Hence, you try to call a method on a null object.

You can not simply instantiate an `ActionController` from another ActionController. (of course, it is possible, with a lot of afford). If you use it this way, you to make sure the new controller instance holds an instance of the ServiceLocator, request, response etc...

You should consider:

- a) is `Admin\LogsController` really a AbstractActionController in your application? (I assume it is not, respectively your code example)
- b) inject the ServiceLocator in to your custom object (LogsController), or a way cleaner: inject the logger instance.

Example:

```
public function getServiceConfig() {
   return array(
       'factories' => array(
           'Admin\LogsController' => function ($sm) {
               $logsController = new LogsController();
               $logsController->setServiceLocator($sm); // you have to implement!
               return $logsController;
       },
   );
}
```